# Linux - GREP print a line with special characters

Tags: utf-8, grep, ascii, special-characters, iconv

I have a problem with grep command, I want all the lines that start with '<', but that is not the problem, when I create a new file with the result of this grep, some special characters are changed for hex symbols

**Grep command**

```
cat OriginalFile.txt | grep '^<' > NewFile.txt
```

**Before Grep**

[image: Before Grep]

**After Grep**

[image]

Is it a way to prevent this change?

**File command**
Diff its OriginalFile.txt
Grep its NewFile.txt

[image]

Comment: Which OS, OS version and grep version do you use?

Comment: the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, and the grep version "grep (GNU grep) 2.20"

Comment: Which program do you use to display the file contents? cat, vim, less, more?

Comment: Add output of `file OriginalFile NewFile.txt` to your question.

Comment: I download the file from the server, but when the process read the file, the layout is moved due to this special char, I mean, I want the data on column 471 of the file, but the data has moved to 472 due to this problem

Comment: I've used the iconv command to convert my NewFile.txt to UTF-8 code and the special character is now ok :D thanks to you @Cyrus